# Codeigniter 2.1 - Combining $data from the __construct and called function

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have several **$data** which are called in almost all functions in controller. Is there a way to create this **$data** in **__construct** function and combine them with **$data** in called function? Example:

```
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('ad_model', 'mgl');
        $this->load->model('global_info_model', 'gi');
        $this->load->model('user_model', 'um');        
        $this->load->library('global_functions');
        $this->css = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\" " . CSS . "mali_oglasi.css\">";
        $this->gi_cat = $this->gi->gi_get_category();
        $this->gi_loc = $this->gi->gi_get_location();        
        $this->gi_type = $this->gi->gi_get_type();       
        }

    function index() {     
        $count = $this->db->count_all('ad');        
        $data['pagination_links'] = $this->global_functions->global_pagination('mali_oglasi', $count, 2);

        $data['title'] = "Mali Oglasi | 010";
        $data['oglasi'] =  $this->mgl->mgl_get_all_home(10);
        $data['loc'] = $this->gi_loc;
        $data['cat'] = $this->gi_cat;
        $data['stylesheet'] = $this->css;
        $data['main_content'] = 'mali_oglasi';

    $this->load->view('template',$data);
    }
```

If I want to put **$data['loc']**, **$data['cat']** and **$data['stylesheet']** in **__construct** I will have to call **$this->data** in **$this->load->view('template',$data);**

Is there a way to combine this two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a private member to your controller and set it in the constructor as you need it:

```
private $data;

function __construct() {
    ...
    $this->data = array(...);
    ...
}
```

Then you can access this private member in all of your controllers actions inside the same controller class.

You can merge two arrays using the [array union operator (`+`)<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

```
$data = $this->data + $data;
```

See as well: [Properties<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: This is basic PHP, you can use it for all your classes, be them controllers or something else. There is much use in learning the basics ;)

Comment: Well I am a self learned programmer, so I maybe skipped a few basic lessons :D

Comment: That has nothing to do with being self-learned or not. It's merely where to look :)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you could do it like this,

```
class ControllerName extends CI_Controller {

    private $_data = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->_data['loc'] = this->gi_loc;
        $this->_data['cat'] = this->gi_cat;
        $this->_data['stylesheet'] = this->css;
    }

    function index()
    {
        // Your data

        // Merge them before the $this->load->view();
        $data = array_merge($this->_data, $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working. Thank you for your help :) (sorry for not getting upvote but hakra was first)